# Gfortran COMMON block with array size

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, fortran-common-block

I am having some trouble with old fortan code that I want to compile on gfortran.

```
 INTEGER NEQ
 DOUBLE PRECISION RE
 COMMON /DM18J/ RE,NEQ
 CALL FUNC(NEQ,RE)
```

The problem with the code is that the function assumes that RE is an array of size NEQ. However, I cannot specify beforehand the size of the array because it comes from the common block.

As the code is quite lengthy I was hoping to fix yhis without resorting to module variables. A thing that I might want to try is to insert NEQ as an argument instead of getting it via the common block.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. Are you saying you have old code that presumably worked at some time and now gfortran is throwing a compile error? Whats the error?  Are you trying to change working code, whats the change?

Comment: It is old code that worked without complaining in Intel Fortran and g95 compilers. A warning is thrown because of a rank mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RE is an array, then it should be declared as such.  Say, for argument, it is of size 100

```
parameter (maxre = 100)
integer neq
double precision re(maxre)
common /dm18j/re, neq
```

When calling your routine, you need to specify the size of the array the function needs to operate on.  This is not necessarily the size of the array.  Your array could have 10000 elements but if you only wish to operate on the first 2, just set NEQ to 2.

```
! sanity check
if (neq .gt. maxre) then
    print *, 'increase the size of maxre to at least ', neq
    stop
end if

call func(re, neq)
```

Comment: I changed the size for all common blocks in the code. This did the trick.